# Certifications and Standards

Tags: standard, certification

I am looking to import machinery (CNCs, extruders, presses etc.) from China to use in my own factory for a specialized production in the USA. Machines are produced by smaller shops in China without certification. Can I just import and use the machines in my own factory? What do I need to do to bring them up to code for use in US?

Comment: First decide which standards your company is planning to comply with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has more to do with safety standards and local codes than electrical engineering and design.

Comment: In the event of injury you will be responsible for that, since you will not be able to take any legal action against the chinese manufacturer. Therefore you will pay all the compensation to the injured workers and a fine too. If you just self injury then it's all up to you.

Comment: @Trevor -- this isn't as localized as you think it is

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel not within the USA no, but the users on here are global, so a lot of opinions would be regionally biased. OP needs to get them on his dock and have the appropriate inspectors / authorities look at them and dictate what he needs to change/add. Not something anyone can answer here.

Comment: @COntinued: Excuse "But someone from EE.SE said it would be fine, or that was all I needed to do!" won't work in a lawsuit.

Comment: Consider the situation if you were to build your own machinery. (Actually, importing machine tools and building your own are not so very different, once you take cleaning and fitting into account)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Two words: "field evaluation"

Most Authorities Having Jurisdiction defer to the opinion of a Nationally Recognized Testing Laboratory (UL, Intertek ETL, CSA, MET, etal)<sup>1</sup> as to whether a machine is safe or not.  Normally, the *listing and labeling* process that conveys that "UL has tested this and found it safe" takes place as part of factory production of the machine.

However, your situation, where you have an unlisted machine already and you want someone to see if it's safe or not, isn't an uncommon one in industry for custom, old, or imported machinery, so UL and company provide an "out" called a *field evaluation* where they come to your site and test/inspect the item of machinery in question, then provide a "one off" field evaluation label for it if it passes all the tests they throw at it.

Expect this to be *not cheap* though -- you're paying for the equivalent of a one-off listing here, so costs are going to be somewhere in the vicinity of getting a product listed + travel costs for the NRTL folks as well.

---

1. The notion of a NRTL that lists products is North American.  However, for the equivalent of listing markings in other countries (the GS product safety mark in Europe, for example), there will be a set of labs (for GS, this is normally either of the two TUVs) that are authorized to test products to the applicable standards and apply the mark if the product passes the tests.

Comment: @Trevor -- as in, that field evaluation label applies to only the machine the UL/... folks came in and tested.

Comment: @Trevor -- "one off" is a figure of speech :)

Comment: Hmm... I stand corrected.. One-Of still makes more sense to me though... but appologies.

Comment: http://www.nytimes.com/2010/07/04/magazine/04FOB-onlanguage-t.html